# Save text from C# textbox to txt file. (Creating a new txt file everytime without same name of files)

Tags: c#, filestream

I would like to get the text from the textbox of my C# application into a .txt file. The issue I have is that the current saved file will overwrite the previously saved file. My current code is:

```
string log = @"C:\log.txt";     
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Create)) {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
         foreach(string line in Textbox1.Lines)
             sw.Write(line + sw.NewLine);
     }
 }
```

Is it possible to save the txt file but without it overwriting the previously saved file? Can someone help me with this.. Thanks

Comment: If you are just using it for logging purpose, use logging framework instead like Log4Net. It will do all this for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
string log = @"C:\log"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss") +".txt";
```

Just add a time stamp to the file name

Comment: ohohoo, ':' in filesystem? nice joke :) what abot "-yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"?

Comment: @user1727958 Welcome to SO! If you think this is the correct answer, please accept it as such

Answer (score 3):

I belive you are talking about appending the lines:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Append)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to the same file you could use FileMode.Append:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Append)
```

Take care if you're in a threaded environment (ie. asp.net which I suspect since you're talking about downloads), regarding file locks and such

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string log = @"C:\log"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff")+".txt";
```

this gives precision up to ten millionths of a second

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
string log = @"C:\log.txt";     

int intCounter = 0;
While(File.Exists(log))
{
  log = @"C:\log"+ intCounter.ToString() +".txt";    
}
```

Comment: these files can't be sorted... pad it with zeros or use stamp

Comment: @sasjaq sure they can be sorted, its called Natural Sort and works flawlessly in Windows Explorer. Its even easier to read then timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

try this ==>

`string log = @"C:\log"+ new Guid().ToString("N") +".txt";`